# Magento 2 how to do minicart ajax update

Tags: magento2, ajax, mini-cart, qty

Is there any way to update the mini cart with ajax without update button.

I am using Magento 2.1.7 how to do mini cart ajax  update when qty increment(+) and decrement(-) inside the mini cart, as qty increment(+) and decrement(-) inside the mini cart product price and the total must change without clicking on update

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can i get module pls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two Methods of updating the minicart

**Method 1:** Using sections.xml

Create **sections.xml** file under `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend` directory

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="module/ajax/index">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

> Note: Put your ajax call URL in place of 'module/ajax/index'

**Method 2:** Using customerData dependency in the script tag

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
    ], function ($, customerData) {

        $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "your_url",
        data: {data : yourData},
        cache: false,
            success: function(response) {

                // reload the minicart
                var sections = ['cart'];
                customerData.reload(sections, true);

            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: When do you want to update the minicart? There must be an action, right? You can use that action url in one of the two above methods.

Comment: Dinesh Yadav as i did as you have shared the procedure only but as  qty increment(+) and decrement(-) inside the mini cart product price and total is not changing

Comment: @trilokkumar There is an **update** button in minicart. You have to trigger the click on that button if you want to update the quantity on increment and decrement button.

Comment: How to trigger the update button in mini cart  Dinesh Yadav

Comment: You have to write the jquery on click of your increment/decrement button.
In this click function, you can trigger the update minicart button as given below

`jQuery('.update-cart-item').trigger('click');`

Comment: `jQuery('.increment-btn').click(function(){ jQuery('.update-cart-item').click(); });`

Comment: See this example I added in previous comment.

Comment: May be you have to set the timeout of few miliseconds before triggering the click on update button. You can ask a new question regarding this.

Comment: it's in .html file jQuery doesn't work  Dinesh Yadav

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84626/discussion-between-trilok-kumar-and-dinesh-yadav).

Answer (score 0):

Modify sidebar.js file. Find this code:

```
events['keyup ' + this.options.item.qty] = function (event) {
            self._showItemButton($(event.target));
        };
```

And change it to:

```
events['keyup ' + this.options.item.qty] = function (event) {
            self._updateItemQty($(event.currentTarget));
        };
```

Now it won't show update button and will update minicart automatically without page refreshing