# magento2 minicart auto update the subtotal on qty change

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, magento2minicart

The current default behavior of the mini cart is when the QTY box is changed an "update" button is displayed which when clicked, updates the subtotal. Is there a way to do this automatically when you change the qty? I commented out the button that appears when you change the QTY currently

```
 <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>

                           <div class="qty-plus-sign">-</div>
                           <input data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           'data-item-qty': qty,
                           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                           }, value: qty"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           class="item-qty cart-item-qty qty-box-additions">
                           <div class="qty-plus-sign">+</div>

                           <!-- <button data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           title: $t('Update')
                           }"
                            class="update-cart-item"
                            style="display: none">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                    </button> -->


                </div>
```

Comment: Check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/263056/59677

Comment: @KishorThummar it doesn't work for me, for some reason none of my functions can be found unless i inject jquery into the acctual "afterRender"